# MVC Report Viewer not showing dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, pivot-table, reportviewer

I'm new to MVC and I need to make a report using Report Viewer, it's been fairly easy with normal queries (I'm using SQL Server 2014). The problem came when I needed to make a report of a dynamic pivot query, it's called reporteNomina.

With normal query the TableAdapter assistant shows its columns, but with my pivot it doesn't show any.

When I need to configure the data of the report it doesn't show the columns of the query.

What can I do? Is there another way to  make a report with a dynamic column query.

Here is my pivot

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(nombre) from Entidad  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
--                  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
--                  ,1,1,'');

select 
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(nombre) 
                   FROM Entidad                
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'SELECT persona, vinculo,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            SELECT p.primerNombre as persona, v.idVinculo as vinculo, e.nombre as nombre, d.valor as valor
            FROM Vinculo v 
            JOIN Persona p on v.numeroIdentificacion = p.numeroIdentificacion
            JOIN Nomina n on v.idVinculo = n.idVinculo
            JOIN Deduccion d on n.idNomina = d.idNomina
            JOIN Obligacion o on o.idObligacion = d.idObligacion
            JOIN Entidad e on e.nit = o.nitEntidad
            where n.idPeriodo = 2

        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum(valor)
            for nombre in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p ';

execute(@query)
```

Thank you.

Comment: There are no columns. I think I'm correct in saying this, but essentially what you're creating is a view. It doesn't output any physical columns you can pull data from. Especially with it being dynamic columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and edit, but do you know how to make a report of a pivot? Preferably with Report Viewer. Or is there another alternative to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Use a crosstab report.